# Alternative to the Inline module

Tags: 7

I've been using inline images with the [Inline](http://drupal.org/project/inline) module to display the attached image like `[inline:dreamspark.jpg=DreamSpark]`, but this module doesn't have a Drupal 7 version, yet.

Is there any alternative to this module? I have many nodes using this module.

Comment: you could enable a WYSIWYG editor plugin for your content, then you can embed the images with a nice UI rather than using the [inline:..] code

Answer (score 1):

There is a Drupal 7 version of that module, it's just in dev at the moment.

I think it's highly unlikely someone else will be developing a competing module along side the development of this one.

I'd advise downloading and installing the [dev version of the module](http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/inline-7.x-1.x-dev.tar.gz), if you get any errors report them back to the [issue queue](http://drupal.org/project/issues/inline) to help push it along.

You can actually check the current issue queue to see if there are any known problems that may stop you being able to use this in your new site...at least you'll know as early as possible.

Comment: I have installed the dev version but it has lots of problem. The module is not updated for a long time.

Comment: @jaypabs as clive said **if you get any errors report them back to the issue queue to help push it along**

Answer (score 0):

My answer is not to use the inline module. In fact i suggest using an alternative setup that seems to work well with content editing. 
May i suggest the use of [ckeditor](http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor) and [ICME](http://drupal.org/project/imce). ckeditor is a nice WYSIWYG style editor that allows you to perform all of the necessary editing including images. ICME will give you a decent interface to upload images, setup quotes for users and few other things. check the docu for more info. you'll be able to get your images into content very easily. both are fully supported in D7.